# Hypothesis testing on data with overlapping groups

Tags: multiple-comparisons, t-test

I frequently run into the following example:

Lot's of genes (order of hundreds of thousands), a few hundred samples stratified into multiple groups. And those groups overlap (i.e. healthy/sick + young/old or something similar).

The task - I need to run a hypothesis test for differences in means for each of the genes. So I normally do t-test with multiple-comparison correction of p-values. However now if I would do that - I would mix some groups. Ideally I would have to run t-test for all different combinations of two groups (healthy youngs vs sick youngs; healthy olds vs sick olds). But this will reduce my already low sample size even more.

So I am curious for suggestions - what is the typical way to approach this situation? ANOVA taking each combination of groups as separate group?

Comment: Sounds like you want to test coefficients in a multiple regression/ancova

Answer (score 1):

You have to decide how you do the error accounting: Are genes falsely attributed to age and to sickness are the same error ("a false discovery")? Otherwise- consider controlling for errors **within** each phenotype. 
In my experience, one typically looks for "sickness genes" so you would use an ANOVA just to control for age/gender but without testing their effects.